# how to draw three.js glowing and shiny sphere or particle system

Tags: three.js, shader, particle-system

I recently found a very cool demo of three.js example at http://workshop.chromeexperiments.com/projects/armsglobe/
I wonder how are those red or blue shiny sphere were created using shader? Many thanks!

Comment: You could always look at the source code and try to "reverse engineer" what is going on. If this is using pixel shaders then you can see the actual code for it!